# Mopub: MOVE_ALL_ADS_WITH_CONTENT MoPubRecyclerAdapter.ContentChangeStrategy doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mopub

I'm just trying get the ads to move with the content of my feed - it makes no sense in my  mind that when your feed increases by 1, that your ads do not adjust their position with it:

```
myMoPubAdapter = new MoPubRecyclerAdapter(this, myInnerAdapter);
myMoPubAdapter.setContentChangeStrategy(MoPubRecyclerAdapter.ContentChangeStrategy.MOVE_ALL_ADS_WITH_CONTENT);
// Create an ad renderer and view binder that describe your native ad layout.
ViewBinder myViewBinder = new ViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.my_ad_layout)
        .titleId(R.id.my_ad_title)
        .textId(R.id.my_ad_text)
        .mainImageId(R.id.my_ad_image)
        .iconImageId(R.id.my_ad_icon)
        .callToActionId(R.id.my_call_to_action)
.privacyInformationIconImageId(R.id.native_ad_privacy_information_icon_image)
        .build();

MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer myRenderer = new MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer(myViewBinder);
myMoPubAdapter.registerAdRenderer(myRenderer);
rv.setAdapter(myMoPubAdapter);
```

I just want the ads to move. For example: Lets say when the app first starts, the ad is at position 2 and subsequently, I inserted a post at the top of my feed, I want the ad to feature in position 3. This just makes logical sense.

If I add the line to the code:

```
`myMoPubAdapter.setContentChangeStrategy(MoPubRecyclerAdapter.ContentChangeStrategy.MOVE_ALL_ADS_WITH_CONTENT);`
```

Nothing is displayed in my feed - the ads which were previously displayed in my feed without this line have now disappeared.

If I take the line out, the ads are displayed again but with the ads maintain their position, so if I have an add in position 2 and I insert a new post at the top of my feed, the ad will still be at position 2.

I thought the setting for the ContentChangeStrategy would allow for the ads to move with the content - why is it now working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The mopub documentation states:

If you want MoPub to keep its ads in the same absolute position when inserting or deleting items, simply call notifyDataSetChanged() from your adapter instead of notifyItemsInserted or notifyItemsRemoved.

What are you calling after your data set changes?